# Jenkins NodeJS plugin compatibility

Tags: node.js, jenkins-plugins

I was wondering is there a way to find out what is the highest version of NodeJS plugin compatible with my Jenkins.
I have Jenkins Jenkins `2.263.4` installed and when I navigate to available plugins page and search for NodeJS plugin I see the message - `Warning: This plugin has dependencies on other plugins that require Jenkins 2.332.1 or newer. Jenkins will refuse to load the dependencies requiring a newer version of Jenkins, and in turn loading this plugin will fail.`

Okay, I tried to find some information what is the right version of the plugin to install it manually through Advanced=>Upload Plugin, but couldn't find any information neither on [Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs/) page nor on [NodeJS GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/nodejs-plugin/releases) page.

[image]

Comment: Every plugin has a detailed usage information section, showing the amount of users using each plugin version per the Jenkins server version. This page is available via the *View detailed version information* link on each Jenkins plugin page. In your case it is available [Here](https://stats.jenkins.io/pluginversions/nodejs.html).